# How can I use an if statement based on a range of index values from a list of string values that has already been created?

Tags: python, indexing, range, slice

I cannot use this if statement in python look at the index range of this list even though documentation shows that I should be able to get the range of the index values using this method.

American_alphabet has already been declared above this section of code.

```
american_alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',"i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
if q2 == american_alphabet[0]:
    print("the first letter of your name is in the range")    
if q2 == american_alphabet[1]:
    print(" is in the range")
if q2 == american_alphabet[2]:
    print("the first letter of your name")
if q2 == american_alphabet[3:6]
        print("umm")        
else:
    print("try again")
```

With this, if I choose the letter g as my answer to q2 then it should be running the print function which should print out the "umm" string that I have listed.
I tried using the range() function with it, I have tried the *start:end* like I have listed currently and even tried using a for and while loop, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in` to compare with a list:

`if q2 in american_alphabet[3:6]:`

Answer (score 0):

There is no colon after `if q2 == american_alphabet[3:6]`, causing the code to fail.

Also, please keep your indentations consistent, line 3 appears to be a syntax error with a double indent.

Comment: I actually forgot to paste it with the colon, but my actual version has the colon.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug this line
`if q2 == american_alphabet[3:6]` and let say `q2="s"` so you are comparing
is `"s"=="def"`  which is not equal .. you can use `in` operator which will work as a `is s in "def"` if yes it will execute the if condition.

**also one more point to add after the in operator also `g` will not give `umm` answer reason**

when you write `american_alphabet[3:6]` 6th index is excluded. if you wanted 6th index which is `g` in your case you should write like this `american_alphabet[3:7]` 6th index included..!